# no "MethodCall" after upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular

We're importing "MethodCall" in our project via

```
import { MethodCall } from "@angular/compiler";
```

This worked until Angular 12. After upgrading to Angular 13, `ng build` throws

```
error TS2305: Module '"@angular/compiler"' has no exported member 'MethodCall'.
```

`package.json` uses `"@angular/compiler": "^13.0.2"`.
Where has "MethodCall" been moved to, or by what has it been replaced?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/42882), `MethodCall` was refactored into `Call`. From the pull request description:

> Currently the compiler has three different classes to represent a "call to something":
>
> 1. MethodCall - foo.bar()
> 2. SafeMethodCall - foo?.bar().
> 3. FunctionCall - Any calls that don't fit into the first two classes. E.g. foo.bar()().
>
> There are a few problems with this approach:
>
> 1. It is inconsistent with the TypeScript AST which only has one node: CallExpression.
> 2. It means that we have to maintain more code, because the various parts of the compiler need to know about three node types.
> 3. It doesn't allow us to easily implement some new JS features like safe calls (e.g. foo.bar?.())).
>
> **These changes rework the compiler so that it produces only one node: Call.** The new node behaves similarly to the TypeScript CallExpression whose receiver can be any expression.